# List of Dictionaries (Search optimization, C#)

Tags: c#, search, optimization, dictionary

I have a List of Dictionaries, `List<Dictionary<String,Object>>`. The key is an identifier of some abstract record. These Dictionaries come from various places. The size of each Dictionary is in the range [0, 1000].

All Dictionaries contain unique keys. After accumulating some Dictionaries I must make a search by key. It could be done by iterating the List and calling search method on every Dictionary or it could be done by copying all Dictionaries into one. These approaches do not offer very good performance. I am interested in ways to optimize this task.

**Edit:**
Thank you guys! Maybe I'll change the accumulation method and as result eliminate the problem itself!

Comment: You're not going to get around iterating the `List` and querying each `Dictionary`. You could optimize if you keep a data structure of keys during `Add` to each `Dictionary`. Maybe time to consider a different storage method?

Comment: What is reason behind keeping them seperate dictionaries?

Comment: @weston because of separate searches;)

Comment: Ok, so sometimes you want to limit to a particuar dictionary, and other times you want to search all? If so, why not search all (by which I mean one all encompasing dictionary), and filter results after. Rather than filtering results (by having seperate dictionaries) and then searching as currently.

Answer (score 1):

Are you expecting there to be lots of key fetches after an initial population phase? If so, amalgamate everything into a single dictionary. If you'll only be doing a *few* fetches, I can't see any way you could get better than asking every dictionary.

Of course you could create a hybrid approach: create a new (initially empty) dictionary for the amalgamated results, and populate it as you're asked for keys - by searching through all the rest each time you're asked for a key which isn't already in your "big" dictionary.

Is there no way of predicting which dictionary would have a particular key?

Answer (score 1):

**If** there is *any* way to localize a dictionary of interest by specifying a `key`, you can try, naturaly, to create a cross association table where you can try to  match the `key` to `dictionary`.

If not, imho, don't see any other option that just iterate over collection and ask for the `key` , may be using standart `for` and *not* nicer linq coding.

Answer (score 1):

Adding to what Jon said, there is an API called as PowerCollections which contains MultiDictionary. If my memory is not corrupted, I believe, you can use this for the purpose mentioned.

http://powercollections.codeplex.com/discussions/242163

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you have lots of dictionaries to "speed up" (assumption of motive) searches that are limited to certain "abstract record" types.

You can get away with one single dictionary, but on limited searches check the result is required abstract record type after finding it. Rather than maintaining a single dictionary for each and every abstract record type as at present.